# Compatibility issues for opening websites, iphone

Tags: iphone, flash, mobile-safari

I'm going to create a website, which is meant to be opened from  mobile phones including iphones. The website may be containing different contents such as Javascript widgets, flash content, images, texts, dropboxes, etc. The website is being built using XHTML and Javascript. What are the common issues that safari faces while opening such a website pls give your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile Safari does not support Flash. Other than that it will cope with anything that a modern desktop browser will cope with.

However, 'coping with' is not the same as 'optimised for'. There are various things you can do to optimise your content for Mobile Safari from a very simple hint about the initial viewport width:

```
< meta name="viewport" content="width=800" / >
```

to a separate CSS style sheet, to completely different content using native Mobile Safari widgets and interaction.

I suggest doing a search for 'optimizing for Mobile Safari'. Apple also has a huge amount of [resources](http://developer.apple.com/safari/).

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet come across any issues that aren't a problem in other good browsers (all except IE). But remember flash does not work, look up http://raphaeljs.com/ for a javascript and canvas tag based alternative.

Personally I'd just get into it and attack any issues if they come up.

Comment: i mean whether there are any known issues for such websites, so that we should avoid using such contents. All browsers may not support everything, and i was pointing that. Btw, do you meant that safari does no support flash content

Comment: Mobile safari does not.

Also, while it's easy to scroll the page in any direction in mobile safari, you can't scroll areas within the page. For example if you have a div with overflow:scroll; users will not be able to scroll it.